# Redefining \hrule to do nothing

Tags: macros, rules

Discl.: I have been using LaTeX for many years, but I am a beginner on the more advanced macro stuff.

For a specific hack of a latex document of mine, I want to override the use of `\hrule` within a command provided by a package I am using. 
Specifically I want to redefine `\hrule` to do nothing, perform the command of the package, and then restore `\hrule` to its previous definition.

Hence I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
\let\hruleold\hrule
\def\hrule(#1)(#2)(#3){}
\packagespecficcommand
\let\hrule\hruleold
```

Which gives me the error:

```
! Use of \hrule doesn't match its definition.
```

What is the correct approach to achieve this?

-- Edit 1 (more specific error) --

I tried the following, as suggested by Herbert:

```
\let\hruleold\hrule
\def\hrule(#1)(#2)(#3){#1,#2,#3}
\maketitle
\let\hrule\hruleold
```

which gives me this error

```
! Use of \hrule doesn't match its definition.
\@packagespecficcommand...skip -\topskip \fi \hrule \@height 
                                                   0.35mm\noindent \advance \...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: I don’t know a `\hrule` macro that accepts three parameters delimited in `(` and `)`. Do you maybe mean the LaTeX `\rule` macro?

Comment: `\let\hrule\relax`, maybe?

Comment: @KeksDose Won't work because `\hrule` is used as `\hrule height 2pt` etc., and if `\hrule` itself is a no-op, the arguments will remain.

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to do a `\let` on a command (such as `\hrule`) that can take optional arguments. Have you tried to localize the (re)definition of `\hrule`? I'm thinking of something along the following: `\begingroup` `\renewcommand\hrule<your specification here>` `<remainder of code for which the new \hrule macro is to be in effect>` `\endgroup`.

Comment: The only way I see is redefining the macros in the package that use `\hrule`. As David Carlisle explains, `\hrule` is a primitive command with a very peculiar syntax and is used in many LaTeX constructs, which will most likely break if `\hrule` is redefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments all sort of errors are bound to happen here. `hrule` even when let to `\relax`, will still leave its argument in the stream. For example the `\textunderscore` macro only takes a `width` argument (the height defaults to the TeX default) and elsewhere it might even have other arguments such as `\hfill` in the definition of
`\hrulefill`. See the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern\z@}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textunderscore}{%
 \leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule\@width.3em}}

\begin{document}

\let\hrule\relax

a\textunderscore b

\end{document}
```

It will be preferable to rather set it's arguments to 0pt i.e.,  `\@width` etc if you know them and perhaps do all these within a group.

Answer (score 14):

You really don't want to do this.

Firstly as has been noted in comments `\hrule` does not take `{}`  or `()` delimited arguments, secondly if you do redefine `\hrule` you not only change the behaviour of an explicit `\hrule` in the document (which by the way isn't correct LaTeX syntax anyway) but you also change (and most likely break) the behaviour of every latex command that uses `\hrule` internally. These include at least   `\vspace` `\hrulefill` `\textunderscore` `\textvisiblespace` `\frame` `\framebox` `\fbox` `\hline` `\cline` `\oval` `\footnoterule`

If I included all the commands and environments that depended on `\vspace` the list would be a lot longer.