# Redefine \hrule without affecting \hline

Tags: rules, hline

I can produce two versions from a single latex source. In one version I want to ignore the instances of `\hrule`. Simply redefining it produces a problem with `\hline`. Hence the MWE below throws an error, but if we comment out the second line then all is well.

I see from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102475/11162) that one shouldn't redefine `\hrule`. So, what would be the best practise here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\hrule}{}

\begin{document}

\hrule

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
    x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline
    f(x) & & & & & \\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: redefining `\hrule` in that way will completely break latex, `hline` is the tip of the iceberg. (ah I just followed your link, and I see it is to me, saying the same thing:-)

Comment: You give no indication of what you want to do,. the best practice is simply not to use `\hrule` rather than define it to nothing then use it, but presumably your real use case doesn't have explicit `\hrule` in the document?

Comment: `\hrule` is a fairly unusual macro, in no small part because it operates in TeX's "vertical" mode. Unless you really know what you're doing, it's best not to modify the properties of `\hrule`. In fact, if you don't really know what you're doing, you may be well advised not to use `\hrule`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefining TeX primitives is almost certain to break LaTeX.

Rather than redefine `\hrule` use  a new command that is defined to be `\hrule` or not depending on the style you need.

```
\documentclass{article}

% \newcommand{\myhrule}{}%  plan a
\newcommand{\myhrule}{\hrule}% plan b

\begin{document}

\myhrule

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
    x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline
    f(x) & & & & & \\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```